# Remove Shipping Address from Paypal Billing agreement form

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to figure out how to remove shipping address from billing agreement form. I can't find any option in **paypal.billingPlan.create** or **paypal.billingAgreement.create** API calls documentation to remove it.

I'm doing an API integration with [Node SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/) for a mobile web.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, answering to my own question.

It seems like a missing feature:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/800

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/4